# i have xampp mysql server running, how do i run code?

Tags: sql, mysql, xampp

i need run code that will create a database and populate tables. i am using windows. how can i run this code?

localhost/phpmyadmin shows nothing, it's a blank page

could it be because i installed the lite version?

Comment: "could it be because i installed the lite version?"

XAMPP lite still has has phpmyadmin installed along with it. You can also, as suggested by the other poster, download the MySQL CLI and use that to execute commands. XAMPP uses the username 'root' and an empty password by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point your browser to http://localhost/phpmyadmin IIRC. You may need to set that up using XAMPP's control panel first, though.

Comment: Through phpmyadmin you can execute raw SQL by clicking the SQL menu or use the GUI it provides.

Comment: Try visiting localhost. This should bring up the XAMPP 'portal', assuming it's set up correctly, which ought to have a link to phpmyadmin somewhere.

Comment: FYI. for the other poster, XAMPP installs phpmyadmin and blocks outside access by default, leaving root blank (but giving you a warning and instructions and how to set it up). Posted here because I'm not privileged to post comments elsewhere!.

Answer (score 1):

You can also connect if you have the mysql command line client which is downloadable from mysql.com.  I personally prefer that, but to each his own:)  If you need to execute code, you should have set up a root password when you installed or it can be done through the control panel and you can use that account in your connection string to execute the code that will populate the tables, etc.